# Group Theory Reference: GxG injects into G

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a name of, or reference to the study of, groups, $G$, with the following property:

(P) There exists an injection $G\times G \rightarrow G$.

I understand the distinction between Hopfian and Non-Hopfian, which certainly seems related i.e. $G$ is Hopfian if the only normal subgroup $N$ which satisfies $G/N\cong G$ is the trivial group. Otherwise it is non-Hopfian. However, I can't prove that property (P) is equivalent to being non-Hopfian, or implies $G$ is Non-Hopfian.

Any reference at all on the topic of groups with property (P) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check here: http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ17_02%2FS144678870001675Xa.pdf&code=4ca75a4111f0f491559d97c60a9e146d Observe that since there exists a trivial embedding $\;G\to G\times G\;$ , groups which fulfill $\;G\cong G\times G\;$ fulfill what you want. Perhaps also this discussion wil help you: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43805/when-is-g-isomorphic-to-g-times-g

Comment: Thank you for your reply, those are just the references I was looking for. I wonder if there is a classification of such groups?